# concatenate rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with Pandas' DataFrame Object.

I have read csv file and I have DataFrame like that:

[image]

I want to concatenate rows between row with sign'|',
it should look like that:

[image]

Has Pandas function like that, to concatenate rows with specific delimiter
or how should I achive that

Comment: Don't use screenshots. Use [simplified, copy-pastable and reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the column of interest has name *txt*.

Define the following function to concatenate the content of group
of fields:

```
def concatRows(grp):
    tt = grp[grp != '|'].to_list()
    rv = ' '.join(tt)
    return rv if len(rv) > 0 else None
```

In your sample data I noticed the "edge case" concerning the last row:
It contains an **empty string**, which should be **discarded**
(instead of creating an empty row).

To take it into account, the above function detects such case and then
returns *None* (actual removal will be done later).

Then apply this function the following way:

```
df.groupby((df.txt == '|').cumsum()).txt.apply(concatRows).dropna()
```

Note that *(df.txt == '|').cumsum()* returns the following groups:

- Group 1 - rows with indices 0 - 2 (withont any '|').
- Group 2 - rows with indices 3 - 7 (starting with '|').
- And so on.

So *grp[grp != '|']* drops the element == '|' (if any).
Then *rv* contains the join result.
But if *rv* is an **empty string**, *None* is returned instead.

Then, any case of *None* be removed by the final call to *dropna*.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is not too big, you can make a string out of it and, then, split it at '|'. Finally, create a new series of the resulted list.

```py
se = pd.Series(['foo', 'foobar', '|', 'bar', '|', '|', 'alpha'])
print(se)
```

```
0       foo
1    foobar
2         |
3       bar
4         |
5         |
6     alpha
dtype: object
```

```py
se = pd.Series(se.str.cat(sep=' ').split('|'))
se = se.loc[se.ne(' ')].reset_index(drop=True)

# with the last step you remove ' ' elements created from consecutive '|'s.
print(se)
```

```
0    foo foobar 
1           bar 
2          alpha
dtype: object
```

Where *se* is the column of the DataFrame.

Comment: If I have 
0       foo
1    foobar
2         |
3       bar
4         |
5         |
6     alpha
dtype: object

it doesn't work correctly, it gives
0    foo     
1     foobar 
2     bar    
3            
4     alpha  
dtype: objec